# Spotify iOS Search Function

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, spotify

I'm in the early stages of creating my own spotify app for iOS, and I want to be able to search for either artist, album or song etc in a table view. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks :)

Comment: You really should have a less vague question, but I think what you are looking for is: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS you should use [CocoaLibSpotify](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify). The `SPSearch` object is what you need - it'll give you back an array of tracks or artists or albums that match a given search, which you can populate a TableView with as you would anything else.